# Universal link - The domain has some validation issue

Tags: ios, https, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Im working on universal link to open the application while tap the url. I am using https server and done all the steps from apple ([Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1)). But the apple universal link validator show below error,

> Your file's 'content-type' header was not found or was not recognized.

[image]

The apple-app-site-association file successfully uploaded to server and the file be like below,

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "J2HBF9A3PZ.com.aors.speaku",
                "paths": ["*","/"]
            }
        ]   
    }
}
```

And apple said no need to sign the `apple-app-site-association` file whether the domain has https.

> If the file is unsigned, it should have a Content-Type of
>   application/json. Otherwise, it should be application/pkcs7-mime.

So my query is how to mention the content type (`application/json`) in this `apple-app-site-association` file???

please help me on this. i don't know what it mean exactly.

Comment: have you ever figured this out? I'm having the exact same issue here.

Comment: I am also facing same issue from last two days.can some suggest here?

Answer (score 53):

I just solved this issue myself. I had to logon to my server and go to the directory where the `apple-app-site-association` file was. In this directory, I had a `.htaccess` file which I modified to include the following lines:

```
<Files "apple-app-site-association">
ForceType 'application/json'
</Files>
```

After doing this, the validation service stopped complaining about the `Content-Type`.

**NOTES:**

- If you don't have a `.htaccess` file, you can just create one.
- I presume the `.htaccess` file should be in the root of your site directory (which is where you would most likely have placed your `apple-app-site-association` file.

Comment: That was clever :)

Comment: I have followed the above steps, still stuck. When I validate on branch/io, it is giving me errors.
- Your server returned an error status code (>= 400). This includes client side and server side errors. Want to know what this means? Click here.
- Content type test did not run. Be sure to define a ‘content-type’ header.
- JSON test did not run. Your file should contain valid JSON.

Comment: Now I receive these errors 
- Your file's 'content-type' header was not found or was not recognized.
 - JSON test did not run. Your file should contain valid JSON.

Comment: I have the same problem. can't resolve the content-type problem

Comment: Same issues... I dont know whats the problem. I added your .htaccess but got : Your server returned an error status code (>= 400). This includes client side and server side errors. Want to know what this means? Click here. Learn More Content type test did not run. Be sure to define a ‘content-type’ header. JSON test did not run. Your file should contain valid JSON.

Comment: If anyone else comes upon this... I tried lots of solutions and this one didn't work for me either... the only one that did was adding this to my .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^apple-app-site-association$ - [env=apple:1]
Header set Content-type application/json env=apple`

Comment: best solution , I spent 6 hours on why domain has validation issue

Answer (score 2):

This one fixed the content type validation in `firebase.json` file.

> ```
>  {
>   "hosting": {
>     "public": "public",
>     "headers": [
>       {
>         "source": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
>         "headers": [
>           {
>             "key": "Content-Type",
>             "value": "application/json"
>           }
>         ]
>       }
>     ],
>     "appAssociation": "NONE"
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: What file did you put this in?

Comment: @Starfs I placed it inside `firebase.json`

Comment: perfect. this got me and running. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress website. Pasting this at the end of .htaccess actually worked for me:

Header set Content-type "application/pkcs7-mime"

Comment: where exactly did you put it?

Comment: At the end of the .htaccess file:
```
...
# Begin DeepLinks - Ophir
<Files apples-app-site-association>
Header set Content-type "application/pkcs7-mime"
</Files>
#END DeepLinks
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is what worked for me:

```
<FilesMatch "apple-app-site-association">
    ForceType application/json
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).