# Universal link not working - JSON file's 'content-type' header was not found

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I followed Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) to implement Universal link but stuck on validating `apple-app-site-association` on our server. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48884387/651409) solution and couple of more as well but still not working. I get the following 'content-type' header not found error when I validate at [branch.io](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox)

I make sure that I follow all documentation steps correctly (Valid JSON, file without .json extension, file placed on the server root folder, tested on real device).

[image]

Comment: Can you show your apple-app-site-association file?

Comment: @ToseefKhilji here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RoWyx7bMtbgVSn9m4gCafdQPllOvz5Vh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Something is wrong on the server side.

Comment: Alright. We are still working to fix this.